# Can I cancel when dividing a negative by a positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say I have $\frac{-h(x^2)}{h}$. Can I cancel the $h$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have then $ -(x^2)$.

Comment: perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could cancel $h$, but leave the negative sign, to get $-x^2$

Comment: Awesome thank you!